# github chrome can't load resources

Tags: google-chrome, github

I did a todo list app a while ago using github pages. It works alright under safari, but the js just doesn't load under chrome. Why? here is the code: https://github.com/randomor/tododoingdone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I see in the Chrome console is:

```
Application Cache Cached event
http://ametopia.com/tododoingdone/border.pngFailed to load resource
http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/deliusunicase/v6/b2sKujV3Q48RV2PQ0k1vqiiT6GQZqXe56UwGtNcbg_g.woffFailed to load resource
```

[image: first error]

That reminds me of the question "[failed to load resource under Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390134/failed-to-load-resource-under-chrome)":
It can be cause by an extension (like for instance AdBlock).

Desactivating AdBlock (even all the extensinos) lead to other javascript loading errors:

[image: second error]

Those are displayed by the console as "others" (and not "scripts") errors.
That can be the result of some other query failing to return properly and blocking all subsequent scripts:
See for instance "[jquery ajax problem in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742049/jquery-ajax-problem-in-chrome)".
Check your resources though, like your images (see "[Resizable: Chrome dev tools console shows GET data: undefined (undefined)](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7293)").

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! I used incognito mode and it was able to load most resources except the border image. I don't have the adblock plugin, but it might be other plugins. I guess it is also happening on your chrome? That's a pretty consistent thing for chrome...:(