# Load Javascript .js (calls a web service) Asynchrosusly into page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

**JScript.js file**

```
function Helloworld() {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/Helloworld",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            document.getElementById('textbox').value = msg.d;
        }
    })
});
```

}

**Default.aspx**

```
    <head runat="server">
    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   //Works Fine when I uncomment this 
   <%--  <script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        (function () {
        var load = document.createElement('script');
        load.type = 'text/javascript';
        load.src = 'JScript.js';
        load.async = true;
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] ||    document.getElementsByTagName('body')   [0]).appendChild(load);
    })();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <input type="input" id="textbox" />
    </form>
    </body>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "KeyHelloworld", "<script type='text/javascript'>Helloworld()</script>");
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string Helloworld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

i am trying to load this JavaScript file into a page asynchronously but the function does not execute above is the  complete code to load the JavaScript file asynchronously

Comment: You don't get any errors in the console?

Comment: no I donot get any errors. i just donot see the output when i call the JavaScript file async . but i see the output when i uncomment this. <%--  <script src="JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>

Answer (score 1):

One glaring issue that I see is that you are embedding your `$(document).ready()` in the `Helloworld()` routine.  Instead, take out the `$(document).ready()`.  It is presumed that if you are calling RegisterStartupScript, you want to execute that Javascript when the document is ready any way, thus making `$(document).ready()` redundant and likely your issue because `$(document).ready()` may have already been invoked before your `Helloworld()` routine is fired.

So, change to the following code and see if it helps:

```
function Helloworld() 
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/Helloworld",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            document.getElementById('textbox').value = msg.d;
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: you are right it works . but only in IE when i try to load it in chrome, mozilla it does not work... do you know why??????

Comment: Does your `Helloworld()` method in your page codebehind get called at all when in chrome or mozilla?

Comment: No!!! the Helloworld() does not get called in Mozilla or Chrome but it does get called in IE

Comment: Take a peak at the following post, and try some of the suggestions; I believe it may help: [jquery ajax problem in chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742049/jquery-ajax-problem-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to load your script asynchronously, but calling it synchronously. Where in the output HTML would the `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` land?

You will need to install a load handler for the dynamically added script:

```
    ...
    load.async = true;
    load.onload = function() {
        Helloworld(); // execute when loaded?
    };
    ...
```

Or execute it directly, i.e. remove the method declaration of `Helloworld`.