# Jquery ajax update issue with chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, jquery

Im having this piece of code

```
<div id="status">content here</div>
 <input name="order_data" type="button"  value="<?php echo $order;?>"  class="besttocart"  onclick="gotocart(this);" />
```

and Javascript

```
function gotocart(e)
{       
   var origtext = $('#status').html();
    if(getCookie('language').toLowerCase() == 'en'){
   $('#status').html('Loading');
    }else{
    $('#status').html('het laden');        
    }

   $.ajax({           
            url: 'index.php?route=foo/bar',
            type: 'post',
            async:false, /*I strongly suspect something here*/
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){

               //do stuff
            }
    });


}
```

The issue is in Google chrome `$('#status').html()` is changing to "loading" or "het laden" when i look through console.but it is not showing in my page my status content is still "content here".
working fine in firefox

Comment: Can you show us with jsfiddle?

Comment: @ExplosionPills That backend ajax is a heavy one..is there something to do with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742049/jquery-ajax-problem-in-chrome

Comment: `async:false` issue with chrome

Comment: I got the issue ..if i change  `async:true` it will work fine..i want `async:false` anyway to do that

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with this line:

getCookie('language'),

because when I changed the code like this,

```
   var origtext = $('#status').html();

    var str=getCookie('language');

   //changed the code here

    if(str && str!='' && str.toLowerCase() == 'en'){
   $('#status').html('Loading');
    }else{
    $('#status').html('het laden');        
    }
```

this works fine.

When the cookie is not set, the function getCookie is returning blank, but toLowerCase is not parsing it in Chrome. Hence the error.

Comment: Is the cookie is being set from php file? See my updated answer. I don't think it is 'async' issue.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using

```
document.getElemetnById("status").innerHTML="SOMETHING";
```

Comment: Thank you Check your spelling and this is not the issue