# Page is not rendered after ajax call in chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome

Following call is failing in chrome and IE but works fine in firefox

```
        var count = 0;
        var timerId=setInterval(function(){
            jQuery.ajax({
            url :"test.htm",
            type : "POST",
            data : sendData,
            success:function(data){
                jQuery(".divClass").remove();
                jQuery("#myId").append(data).addClass("newClass");
                clearInterval(timerId);
                },
                error :function(data){
                    if(count == 20){
                        jQuery(".divClass").remove();
                        jQuery("#myId").append(data).addClass("newClass");
                        clearInterval(timerId);
                    }
                    count++;
                }
        });
           },1000);
```

In debugging control is lost at `jQuery(".divClass").remove();` in success method. All that remains is the header of the modal box. After all of this call when I re run the append and remove calls from console they seem to work fine. Problem is happening only in the success method of ajax call.

I tried all the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742049/jquery-ajax-problem-in-chrome). Any other suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: you forgot to close `setInterval()`: add this at the end of your script: `});`

Comment: you also need a length of time with the end of the `setInterval` (you probably know this)

Comment: Yup that is present. Missed it while coping code.

Comment: I might be wrong, but is this actually working (scope)? `clearInterval(timerId);`

Comment: Similar code seems to work fine in chrome and ie here http://jsfiddle.net/ptm0jo52/1/