# jQuery.Ajax not working in Chome, but it is in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have some ajax that is causing an issue in Chrome but not IE. I trapped the traffic using Fiddler and I compared it to the IE traffic and I see that the content type is missing in the Chrome request, and the verb in the chrome request is set to "Options" rather than post.  When I modify those two things and resubmit with Fiddler it works fine.  Any ideas what is causing these issues?

```
jQuery.ajax({ 
   url: url,
   type:'POST',
   contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
   cache: false,
   data: request, 
   success:function(data) { 
      alert("Success!!!"); 
   }, 
   error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
      alert("Error : " + errorThrown + " textStatus: " + textStatus );
   } 
});
```

Comment: Here ya go:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742049/jquery-ajax-problem-in-chrome

Comment: @Patrick, thanks, that helps give me a better error message.  The problem is not solved. The error message states "Network Error: Failed to execute 'Send' on XmlHttpRequest".  What is it talking about an XmlHttpRequest when I am dealing with Json?

Comment: Instead of contentType, use dataType: 'json'

Answer (score 0):

Here is the structure of the ajax I use in my project and it works perfect in IE and Chrome,

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'api/Test/GetData',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: SearchRequest,
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
      });
```

The difference is, I use dataType: 'json' and not contentType.